# Retain Dynamic Controls in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have page on which I have 10 panel controls. Each of these Panels have approx 10 `TextBoxes` which I create dynamically using following code

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = "txt_" + Month + "_" + Stage;
txt.Text = Value;
if (v == 0)
   Panel_0.Controls.Add(txt);
else if (v == 1)
   Panel_1.Controls.Add(txt);
```

I have some values retrieved from Database in those `TextBoxes`. I can change those values and I also have one Save button. On Click event of this button, I loop through `TextBoxes` of each panel to save modified data.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox txt in Panel_0.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {

    }
}
```

But, when I click on Save button, I can not find any `TextBox` Control in my for loop.
Also on post back, these controls gets vanished from my page.
How can I save the Controls and their Data so that I can retrieve it on Button Click event.

Comment: They will be lost after post back you should maintain they.

Comment: @Vijay  Please mark my answer as accepted, if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic controls are lost after postback. You have to re-created them after each post-back. you will have to make use of `View-State`

```
protected int NumberOfControls
{
    get{return (int)ViewState["NumControls"];}
    set{ViewState["NumControls"] = value;}
}


private void addSomeControl()
{
    TextBox tx = new TextBox();
    tx.ID = "ControlID_" + NumberOfControls.ToString();
    Page.Controls.Add(tx);
    this.NumberOfControls++;
}
```

Please visit the following Urls:

[ASP.Net Dynamic Controls ViewState: Retain state for dynamically created controls on PostBack](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Dynamic-Controls-ViewState-Retain-state-for-dynamically-created-controls-on-PostBack.aspx)

[Retaining State for Dynamically Created Controls in ASP.NET applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i)

[ViewState in Dynamic Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35360/ViewState-in-Dynamic-Control)